# (Virtual) Gun laying given known values

Tags: trigonometry

Good afternoon and I hope you are all doing well.

To preface this question, I am trying to work out some maths for getting the desired elevation of a gun barrel in a military simulator.

Given two positions, the gun's location and the target both at the same height, I can work out, with a range card, the elevation of the gun to hit the target as I know the distance between them. No problem.

However, as soon as we start taking hills into account, I am trying to find out the answer to two questions:

- Let's say the horizontal distance from a gun to a target is 1000 metres. If the gun is at a height of 0 metres and the target at a height of 50 metres, how can I work out what to add/subtract from the gun's elevation to put the target in the trajectory of the gun?
- Secondly, are there any efficient, maths-based answers to figuring out if hills or other terrain features are located in the gun-target line (for example, does the desired trajectory collide with a hill between the gun and the target.

Thank you for your time. I have added a screenshot of the existing range card in-game so that you can see the numbers I am working with.

[Range card for in-game L118 Light Gun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFEM5.png)

Comment: You should take a look at https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/projectile-motion

Comment: Ohh thank you. I was in this website earlier today but on a different calculator. I'll have a go with this.

Comment: Usually with a firearm if your position is fixed, the only thing that affects distance is the angle. Can you provide more details about the values in the range card? Keep in mind that air resistance plays significant role so look for models that take air resistance into account.

Comment: Thank you. What I am looking for is the new angle given the target is now at a height of 50 metres instead of 0 metres

Comment: Not sure if you are asking a practical question or a straight mathematical one.  In real life, air resistance and spin can alter the straight Newtonian computation.  Baseball pitches need not drop at all, if the ball is thrown with sufficient spin.  Not sure how bullets work, but I wouldn't assume anything simple.

Comment: For instance:  I would expect the [Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) to be very strong for a round shot, though I would not be surprised to learn that the traditional bullet shape cuts this down a lot.  I imagine this is well documented.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Those things are not in the scope of the game's ballistics although very interesting points for further research. I am just looking for a way of working out the new gun elevation given the height difference in perfect conditions.

Comment: To find angle one needs to solve system $L=(v_0 \cos \alpha )t$, $H=(v_0 \sin \alpha )t - \frac{g t^2}{2}$ for $t$ and $\alpha$, where $L$ is horizontal distance, $v_0$ is initial velocity of projectile, $\alpha$ is elevation angle of barrel from horizontal direction, $H$ is difference of height of target and gun, $g$ is gravity acceleration, $t$ is projectile flight time. Using $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1$ system can be transformed into biquadratic equation for $t$, which can be solved analytically and then $\cos \alpha$ can be found.

Comment: To check if projectile colliding hills during flight one can check that every point of parametric curve $x=L=(v_0 \cos \alpha) \tau$, $y=(v_0 \sin \alpha) \tau - \frac{g \tau^2}{2}$, with $0 < \tau < t$ lies above earth surface ($y$ is greater than $y$ of earth at the same $x$).